# How to delete only rows that comply with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below and the select return the rows that I want to delete but when I ran the entire query oh boy it deleted everything from the table.

How do I change the delete to only delete the rows returned by the select after the where:

```
delete  from StaffSecurityItems
  WHERE exists (
    SELECT  ssi.SysSaffID
  FROM StaffDeparment sd, CustomFieldValues cfv, StaffSecurityItems ssi
  where cfv.SysCustomFieldID = '-9223372036854749962'
  and cfv.FieldValue = 'Yes'
    and sd.SysStaffRoleID =11
  and cfv.SysDeparmentID = sd.SysDeparmentID
   and ssi.SysSaffID = SysSaffID
    and ssi.ItemName in ('EnrollNewMember','EditEnrollmentInfo')
    and ssi.SysStudyID ='-9223372036854759558');
```

My main issues is with the delete, I need to make sure that in only deletes what is being returned by select.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: If you temporarily change the word `delete` to `select *` you will get a preview of **exactly** which rows will get deleted from the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `SELECT` works, why not simply replace the `SELECT`? What you have there is a query that **will delete every row** in the table `StaffSecurityItems` *if* the query within the `EXISTS` returns even a single row (what rows it finds is meaningless, due to a lack of a correlated query).

```
DELETE SD
FROM StaffDeparment sd
     JOIN CustomFieldValues cfv ON cfv.SysDeparmentID = sd.SysDeparmentID
     JOIN StaffSecurityItems ssi ON ssi.SysSaffID = sd.SysSaffID --guessed alias
WHERE cfv.SysCustomFieldID = '-9223372036854749962'
  AND cfv.FieldValue = 'Yes'
  AND sd.SysStaffRoleID =11
  AND ssi.ItemName in ('EnrollNewMember','EditEnrollmentInfo')
  AND ssi.SysStudyID ='-9223372036854759558'
```

And, as mentioned in the comments, the ANSI-92 syntax has been around for 27 years! There's no reason you shouldn't be using it: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: What are your thoughts on using explicit JOIN syntax (`INNER JOIN` vs just `JOIN`), and avoiding acronym table aliases? Whenever I use something like `StaffDepartment AS sd`, I find I constantly have to refer back to the definition, to remind myself which acronym applies to which table.

Comment: `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are synonyms in T-SQL, so I personally don't write `INNER`; but certainly it's a point of preference. As for aliasing of tables, @Zack , if you're having to constantly refer to the `FROM` to remind you which is which, then your aliases either aren't representative of the object, like `a` for `CustomerOrders`, or you're not being consistent. Maybe you aliased `CustomerOrders` with `O` in one query, but `CO` in another. Both representative **and** consistent aliases are important, not just one or the other.

Comment: For example, I have objects at work called `brpolicy`, `yyclient` and `daprospect`, but their aliases are always `BPY`, `BCM` and `PCM` respectively; because that is what objects that represent the tables are called within the application. As a result they are very consistent, and the entire office (DBAs, SQL developers and application developers), all know what the `BPY` is and it works incredibly well. Because we're all consistent with our naming/aliases.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks!